# How to control picture size in qgis2web?

Tags: leaflet, qgis2web

I have created a map and imported geolocated pictures.  I have no issues with the map in QGIS it self all works great the pop-ups work great.

My issue is when I export the map with qgis2web I get the full size image when I hover or click on the icon.  Is there a way to make it display at a reasonable size? at least one that does not crop the picture and the user can see what it is.

Using: ***QGIS 3.22 with qgis2web 3.16.0 - exporting to leaflet***

See samples below:

**Image 1 in QGIS no problem 600px width**
[image: Image 1 in QGIS no problem]

**Image 2 webmap from qgis2web) original size 2400px (width)**
[image: Image 2 webmap from qgis2web) original size 2400px (width)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guys at qgis2web helped with this bit of info:

Edit the index.html and qgis2web.css as follow:

**index.html**
in the var popupContent the photo features property replace it with this at the end.

```
.trim() + '" '+ 'class=popupImage' +'>' : '') + '</td>\
```

**qgis2web.css**
add the following at the end of the file:

```
.popupImage {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.popupImage2 {
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
}
```

That was it!  It works now!  The only issues is that every time I update the map I will have to make the changes again.

[image]